# How can i display admin users as product's attribute options in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configurable-product, product-attribute, custom-options

I need to add a select type product attribute  (same as size/color) Magento 2. but options of this attribute should came from custom table (like admin user).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems odd to show admin users as options in frontend.
Yet you can achieve this by adding a new product attribute with the source model as admin user model.
It will return the admin users in the dropdown.

Comment: I think you don't  have solution. i just given an example